# Automating Login Process Using Seleinum PageObjects

Tags: java, design-patterns, selenium

I'm very much new to Selenium and I started automating the login process. I used PageObjects for this purpose. I have a `LoginPage` which has a method like this:

```
public MyHomePage login(String username,String password)
{
    username.sendKeys(username);
    password.sendKeys(password);

    signInButton.click();
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver,MyHomePage.class);
}
```

This works well with correct username and password. But I dont want to repeat  the same code for handling invalid cases. Surely for invalid cases, the object that is returned will be the same `LoginPage`. I wish I could code my `login` method that way.

Any best practice way to so? Since login is very common , there should be a better approach for my case.

Or is it I have to write separate code for invalid case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refact the part that does the login to another method which can be common between login and login unsuccessfully as such:

```
private void login(String username,String password){
  username.sendKeys(username);
    password.sendKeys(password);

    signInButton.click();
}

public MyHomePage login(String username,String password)
{
    login(username, password);
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver,MyHomePage.class);
}

public LoginPage loginUnsuccessfully(String username,String password)
{
    login(username, password);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even getting more extravagant!  You could make a custom `TestRunner` which literally finds all `@Test` methods that you have put in, then it your `TestRunner` would say

> If `TestA` fails: `retry`.
>
> If `TestA` fails again: `retry`.
>
> If `TestA` fails again: this is a legitimate failure.

With this concept, you'd obviously have to tie it in with whatever running software you are using. TestNG, jUnit, etc.

This is pretty much the same concept that we use here at the company I work at.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your elements to an elements class, ex: MyHomePageElements.java.

Then initialize them when calling your MyHomePage class.

**MyHomePage.java**

```
public MyHomePage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, MyHomePageElements.class);
}

public void login(String username, String password) {
    MyHomePageElements.username.sendKeys(username);
    MyHomePageElements.password.sendKeys(password);
    MyHomePageElements.signInButton.click();
}
```

Then in your test class (or if you're going to use login a lot, put this somewhere as a login reference and not as a test):

```
@Test
public void adminlogin() {
    MyHomePage homepage = new MyHomePage();
    homepage.login("admin", "p@$$w0rd");
}
```

Then if you need a failing case:

```
@Test
public void failedlogin() {
    MyHomePage homepage = new MyHomePage();
    homepage.login("admin", "wrongp@$$w0rd");
    homepage.somemethodcheckingforfailure();
}
```

**Explanation**:

The idea is that your methods behind the test class should be immutable, the changes to your test should be done sparingly, and if elements change over time through improvements or design changes, everything is organized in a way for you to easily change things without writing over your methods and tests. I go even further and keep my usernames, passwords, urls, etc., in a properties file and refer parameters from there. If I need multiple values I use parameter injecting methods depending on the test tool (JUnit and TestNG).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using examples in C# but I have also achieved something similar in java but sending the return page as an extra argument

http://sellotapetest.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/navigation-in-page-objects-returning.html?m=1