# Page Factory with properties

Tags: selenium

i m confused :( as automation framework if i use page object/factory than i should use object repository I mean Properties file in selenium webdriver. 
OR
i can use one at a time either page factory or properties file approach.

i m using  this code:

```
package Pages;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginPage {

final WebDriver driver;
static Properties prop = new Properties();

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "form-login-username")
private WebElement usernameEditbox;

@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "password")
private WebElement passwordEditbox;

@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "Log In")
private WebElement loginButton;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
this.driver = driver;
}

public void enterUsername(String login) {
usernameEditbox.clear();
usernameEditbox.sendKeys(login);
}

/*public void enterUsername(String login) {
    signInUsername.clear();
    usernameEditbox.sendKeys(login);
    }*/

public void enterPassword(String password) {
passwordEditbox.clear();
passwordEditbox.sendKeys(password);
}

public void clickSigninButton() {
loginButton.click();
}
public  LandingPage login(String login, String password) {
enterUsername(login);
enterPassword(password);
clickSigninButton();
return PageFactory.initElements(driver, LandingPage.class);
}
}
```

Instead on defining @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "form-login-username")
private WebElement usernameEditbox; in same file how i can call it from OR.properties ???

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659671/automating-login-process-using-seleinum-pageobjects/20668756#20668756) I made to somebody else using Page Object Pattern.

Properties files would be no different than just separating your elements to an elements class file and initializing them in the way I describe in the linked post.

Edit: Example of an elements class:

```
@FindBy(css = "button[id='Save']")
public static WebElement buttonSave;

@FindBy(css = "button[id='Cancel']")
public static WebElement buttonCancel;
```

And so on. The elements class is just meant to hold on to your elements. You then use those elements via the PageFactory.init example shown in the link above. It would be preferred to have a separate elements class for each "page." I hope that's clear enough :)

Comment: hey thanks a lot can u share scripts of MyHomePageElements.class as per your suggestion link.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the page object pattern, then in theory each selector will only exist once. Therefore, it is acceptable to in affect hard code them in the page object class rather than create some kind of repository or external resource.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Test Automation Framework (TAF) which have enhanced Page Object Factory implementation. It will allow you to use a properties file for your locators for your Page Factory classes.

You can mention a default locator file for your factory and can also override it at runtime (if required) by providing a external file.

http://menonvarun.github.io/taf/

http://menonvarun.github.io/taf/pages/locator_in_taf.html