# selenium structuring patterns java

Tags: java, design-patterns, selenium, junit, automation

I'm pretty new to Selenium, but have good coding experience

I'm working on automation of very complex web application. 
For my testing i'm using junit framework.

I don't want my classes to expand to gigantic sizes, so this is how i'm dividing my automation per page. For ex. i have homepage. From it i can get to settings, dashboard and many other pages. So all modifications/functionality related to homePage i keep at homepage class. Then for each next page i have another class, where i'm creating webdriver and assigning it to the previous page webdriver. So again each class is reflecting functionality i can achieve on that particular page.

So let's say i have 4th level page, i will have a class of that 4th level, on creating it will go to create 3rd level page, 3rd will create 2nd level first ans so on,and at some point i will get down to the very first login page. Basically i have a tree with my loginPage in the head of it.

It works very well and i have no problems with it until it comes to junit. 
I like an idea of closing the browser in my @After class and i'm having different page classes.. How can i bend it all together that no matter what class-Page i create and work with at my test, my after method is closing that browser?

Thanks

Comment: How about `webDriver.quit()`?

Comment: Use only one web driver (create it inside your specific JUnit test case) and instead of creating a web driver for each page, just create methods in each page-class that you can pass the driver to.

Comment: Awesome. thank you. I wasnt creating webdriver in my each class, but rather only on the very first login page, then i was passing it to my other classes. I'll change structure so my first main page takes that webdriver as a parameter and then will be creating one each time before test and will be able to quit it in the after method.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this, is to have an `After` method in the class that all your tests extend.  For example:

```
Class A extends T
Class B extends T

Class T {
    WebDriver driver;

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Now when your `A#testMethod1` finished, it will perform `tearDown()` from the inherited `@After` method.

Also as far as your pages go, do as @CeilingGecko stated and use only 1 webdriver instance.  You could do it like this:

```
Class A extends T {
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        loginPage.login("username", "password");
    }
}

Class LoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void login(String user, String password) {
        // driver.doStuff()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have chain class3 extends 2, 2 extends 1 and 1 extends T that has After. I'm running my test and it goes from 3->2->1->T. It is failing with nullpointexception and i'll find where soon :) the question is why After wasn't executed?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you without actually seeing the code :(  It might help if you had a framework for your stuff.. give http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium a try.. it's  a framework that was dedicated for getting started using selenium.. might give you great practices on how to create your tests.  In the readme, it gives you the download link.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Pagefactory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory). I have a relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659671/automating-login-process-using-seleinum-pageobjects/20668756#20668756) with an example.